# How can i Insert all dates between start and end date into table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

let's say i have 2 table

First one is "Orders"

```
Select * from Orders
```

give me this results.

```
 Order_ID   Date_Start          Date_End                                   Order_Name
2059    2020-11-13 00:00:00.000 2020-11-14 00:00:00.000             order1
2060    2020-12-12 00:00:00.000 2020-12-22 00:00:00.000             order2
```

and second table say it "Dates"

This is desired results for Dates table.i need to insert dates between two dates to that table for each order ID.

```
Date                    Type1   Type2   Type3   Type4   Type5   Order_ID
2020-11-13 00:00:00.000 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2059
2020-11-14 00:00:00.000 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2059
```

Comment: Does `dates` already have rows?  What happened to order 2060?

Comment: In C# or Sql code?

Comment: @GordonLinoff i manually type Dates results for order_ID 2059 only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to generate data for each date for each order, use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select orderid, date_start as date, date_end
      from orders
      union all
      select orderid, dateadd(day, 1, date), date_end
      from cte
      where date < date_end
     )
select *
from cte;
```

You can also use a recursive CTE in an `insert` statement:

```
with cte as (
      select orderid, date_start as date, date_end
      from orders
      union all
      select orderid, dateadd(day, 1, date), date_end
      from cte
      where date < date_end
     )
insert into dates (date, order_id)
    select date, order_id
    from cte;
```

Comment: That's great i can populate my datagridview with dates now but i cant use cte with insert statement i need those dates in my Dates table so i can connect 2 table and add other things for each day can u show me an example ? cte in insert statement

Comment: hey your insert query give me 2 of the same result every time do u know why ? i'll update my answer to show what i mean

Comment: @Kutayyorgun . . . Can you ask a *new* question?  However, I suspect that you are running multiple times and not truncating the table between the runs.